# C++ (Windows) Get the current network adaptor for running process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I see the GetAdaptersAddresses and GetAdaptersInfo functions and can get lists of all adaptors but I'm looking to get the current adaptor that is in use for the process I'm running, how is it I go about getting this?

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense ... there is no "network adapt**e**r for running process". There are network adapters and processes. Processes may open sockets and the packets within those may be routed via one or more (!) adapters, depending on your network adapter metric, routing and a lot of other factors. You cant ... actually ... control which adapter is being used, you can make your packets very likely being routed over adapter X or Y but ... thats basically a game of chance even though you may win most of the time

Comment: I'm looking simply to get the current network in use, say a wifi connection is on as is Lan and both are connected to the same router so have the same ip, what one is my app using?

Comment: Apps don't have IPs.

Comment: I hear you but, surely, there must be some sort of event in Windows to know when a network change has happened?

Comment: Sort of, yes - you can listen for [device events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but that wont get you anywhere and its also completely different kind of beast which has nothing to do with your question, there also [.NET classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) for network events, also : [NLM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  Perhaps your goal can be fulfilled a different way but you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: My application has settings based on current network speed, just looking to know when to redo a speed test, I know already when ip changes but that in itself is not really that good for redoing a test as the ip might be dynamic. I thought that if ip + adaptor name were different from last check then that would do but I dont know what adaptor is being used in the first place.

Comment: Listening for NLM events would be your only choice, in that case then

Comment: [How to use the Windows NLM API to get notified of new network connectivity](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34650/How-to-use-the-Windows-NLM-API-to-get-notified-of)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) to enumerate connections, and the process ID associated with each.

Then you filter that list to get rid of the ones that aren't associated with the process you care about.

Comment: i think you might want to read what he wrote again ... because your words do not answer his question

Comment: @specializt: I've read it again. If you see a disconnect, perhaps you can be more specific about what it is--I'm not seeing it. I've also read your comment on the question. I think you're the one who's misunderstood the question. You pointed out that the adapter used by a particular connection isn't known *a priori*, but he's not asking about foreknowledge, only about what's *currently* happening.

Comment: you're talking about **connections** whereas he was asking about **network adapters** -- totally and completely different things

Comment: @specializt: Based on what he's said he already knows about (GetAdaptersInfo) he can find the local IP address of each adapter. I've simply added enough to let him trace from a connection to what he already knows about (i.e., retrieve a list of connections, which includes the local IP used by each). Absent a reason to insult his intelligence, there's no point in reiterating what he's clearly stated that he already knows.

Comment: um ... you **do** know that adapters can have *no* or even *multiple* adresses for different protocols, ya? Linking connections to adapters basically is a *game of chance* and unless you're writing malware thats hardly acceptable. Professional software usually displays a choicebox which lets the user select the primary, desired network adapter if its really necessary to do so.